# OpenVPN: Allow server to reach client without redirecting all client traffic over VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

So I've set up a reasonably basic `tun` OpenVPN server, and am having trouble getting it so that the server can communicate with all of the connected clients.

I currently have two sets of clients, some that don't use the VPN to connect to the internet (just to talk to the other clients), and some that use `redirect-gateway` to send all of their traffic over the VPN.

With how I have it set up, all of the connected clients can communicate with the server, and with the other clients. However, from the server, I can only reach (e.g. ping) the clients that are using `redirect-gateway` to send all of their traffic through the VPN. The clients not using that config can ping the server, but the server cannot ping back (they don't respond to it and it times out).

How can I set up the routing so that the server can still communicate with clients even if they don't use the VPN as their default gateway?

Here's the relevant server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
push "topology subnet"
server 10.7.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

In the client config directory on the server, each client has a file like this (just to give each a static IP):

```
ifconfig-push 10.7.0.10 255.255.255.0
```

The relevant bits of the local client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote {server's public ip} 1194
float
keepalive 15 60
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1
tun-mtu 1500
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
comp-lzo yes
nobind
```

The clients that are using the VPN for internet access add `redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp` to their config.

I'm using `ufw` for my server's firewall - here's the relevant config (in /etc/ufw/before.rules):

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/8 -j SNAT --to-source {server's public ip}
```

As this is running on an OpenVZ VPS, I cannot use `MASQUERADE`, but the above seems to work just as well.

Any ideas on how to set this up properly? Thanks in advance. If it matters, the server is running CentOS.

Comment: Do not push `redirect-gateway` at all?

Comment: That is, eliminate `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` from the server config (and all the `ifconfig-push` files) and `route-nopull` from the client config.

Comment: Okay I've switched it to not push `redirect-gateway` at all - didn't realize that it can just be set on the client. Also removed `route-nopull` / etc. The `ifconfig-push` files are necessary to give each client a static IP as OpenVPN seems to disregard ipp.txt even with `ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 0`. Unfortunately, it still exhibits the same behavior even with these changes - only clients using `redirect-gateway` respond to the server.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect the changes I've made.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for serverfault?

Comment: Can you add the routing tables from the server and a client? Can you test quickly with your firewall disabled from a test client to see if it works to rule out FW rules that may be needed rather than OpenVPN rules? Quick ideas but give it some thought and effort if you want once you get to it.